# MySQL inner join with two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I'm very new to MySQL and PHP and I'm struggling with inner joins between two tables. I'm constructing a script that reads an os commerce database and tells me which products is currently on back order. In order for the product to be on back order a value in the products_attributes table is set to '134', however it only reads the product_id and not the product_model which is in the 'products' table.

```
products_attributes(table name)
  options_values_id
  product_id

products(table name)
  product_id
  product_model
```

I want to select items that have the value of '134' in the products_attributes table then match the product_ids from both tables to get the product_model from the "products" table. I feel like the code is very easy but for some reason I'm struggling with how to construct the query and to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT product_model  FROM products as p,products_attributes as pa WHERE p.product_id = pa.product_id and pa.options_values_id = 134`

or

`SELECT p.product_model FROM products p INNER JOIN products_attributes as pa ON (p.product_id = pa.product_id) WHERE pa.options_values_id = 134`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're asking how to get the product ID of anything have an attribute of 134
In that case, no `JOIN` is required.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    product_id
FROM
    products_attributes
WHERE
    options_values_id = 134
```

If you want the product_model then you could form the `JOIN` like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.[product_model]
FROM
    products p
JOIN
    product_attributes pa
    ON pa.[product_id] = p.[product_id]
WHERE
    pa.[options_values_id] = 134
```

So the `JOIN` stipulates how the two tables are related to each other. Once there is a valid `JOIN` you can use the joined table nearly anywhere in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_model
from products p
inner join products_attributes pa on pa.product_id = p.product_id
where pa.options_values_id = '134'
```